# xlC compiler error

Tags: compiling, aix, xlc

I am trying to compile a file named md5.c with xlC compiler this way:

```
cc md5.c
```

and it throws me an error that says

> ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .main

Here I attach the md5.c file and as you can see there is no main in it (neither in the md5.h), so I don't know why I am getting that error

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include </home/inst6/sqllib/include/sqludf.h>
#include </home/inst6/sqllib/include/sqlca.h>
#include </home/inst6/sqllib/include/sqlda.h>
#include "md5.h"


/*--------------------------------------------------*/
/* MD5 Hashing                                      */
/*--------------------------------------------------*/

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void SQL_API_FN md5_c(
SQLUDF_VARCHAR      *in,
SQLUDF_CHAR      out[33],
SQLUDF_SMALLINT  *innull,
SQLUDF_SMALLINT  *outnull,
SQLUDF_TRAIL_ARGS) {

char *t;

t = md5( in );
strcpy( out, t );
free( t );

*outnull = 0;
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You received that error *exactly because* there is no main function. You've asked the compiler to create an executable; an executable needs a main function. Perhaps you meant to tell the compiler to compile-only, using the `-c` option?